# How to pass value from view to another view in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to use laravel. I try to passing value from view to another view 
in laravel.

I try to passing and I show in blade like {{ $req }}
but I got error

i want pass value poli/dokter
This is my **first blade** :

```
 <form action="{{URL::to('/getHalaman')}}" method="post" id="form1">
    <!-- <label>Selamat Datang&nbsp,&nbsp{{$result->nama}} </label> -->
    <div style="text-align: center;  margin-right: 1%;">Jaminan : 
      <select id="select-jaminan" name="select_jaminan" style="width: 200px;">
        <option id="option-jaminan">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value="BPJS">BPJS</option>
        <option value="UMUM">UMUM</option>
        <option value="ASURANSI">ASURANSI</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div style="text-align: center;">Periksa : 
      <select id="select-periksa" name="select_periksa" style="width: 200px;">
        <option >-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value="poli">Poli</option>
        <option value="dokter">Dokter</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <br>
```

This is my **second blade** :

```
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <h3>Daftar Periksa</h3>
    <!-- {{ $req }} -->
```

This is my **controller** :

```
function getHalaman(Request $req){
    if($req->select_periksa == 'poli'){
        return redirect('daftarPeriksaPoli');
    } else{
        return redirect('daftarPeriksa');
    }
}
```

This is my **route** :

```
Route::get('/daftarPeriksa', function() {
return view('daftarPeriksa');
});

Route::post('/getHalaman', 'userController@getHalaman');

Route::get('/daftarPeriksa', 'userController@getDaftarPeriksa');
```

Someone can help me, how to passing value from first view and show in second view ?

Very Thank you, if someone want to help me :))

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want accually

Comment: Can you show from where you are trying to pass it to another view?

Comment: i want to pass value from selected option :  poli or dokter

Comment: You want to pass the selected value when you submit the form? i.e. to a you want to pass data to view from the controller?

Comment: Where are the controllers that server your blade files? The one you included only returns a redirect

Comment: @KamalPaliwal i want pass value from selected when submit and show in second view sir.. can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Controller Method

```
function getHalaman(Request $req){
    if($req->select_periksa == 'poli'){
        return view('daftarPeriksa')->with(['req' => $req]);
    } else{
        return view('your_second_view')->with(['req' => $req]);
    }
}
```

And Fetch this value In the blade file

```
{{ $req->select_jaminan }}
```

Comment: i try this but not change anything, any idea sir ?

Comment: @YeruAdi I updated the answer. You can directly go to the View instead to Route with request data.

Comment: i try with your answer sir, and on view show like this :

Comment: POST /getHalaman HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/* ...... Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=q84LpCkuf7JBLOOecXkCoN5uf2WyCELEssBE80m7; laravel_session=wHmXqstiXtc2HilJGjSytVBem0Yyg2BL69SI8R1b select_jaminan=UMUM&select_periksa=dokter&_token=q84LpCkuf7JBLOOecXkCoN5uf2WyCELEssBE80m7

Comment: how can i got value just :  'UMUM' and 'dokter' sir ?

Comment: fetch value like this {{  $req->select_jaminan }} and {{ $req->select_periksa }}

Comment: thankyou sir, i try with your answer and my program can run perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

`<?= {{ $req }} ?>`

Comment: can you check my controller or route dude ? what wrong on my controller or route ?

Comment: In the function getHalaman has the parameter $ req, so at the route you need to declare it as follows:

Route::post('getHalaman/{req}', 'userController@getHalaman');

Comment: my controller sir ? that is true ?

Comment: i got error like this sir : "Undefined variable: req"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
return redirect('daftarPeriksa');
```

you can use something like:

```
return view('daftarPeriksa')->with('req',$req);
```

Comment: if you are using the with() method, you dont actually need to specify the name of the var you are passing to your view. just $req corresponds in your blade too $req. no you are justpassing 2 vars with the same name, so the var in your blade is the LAST corresponding var from your controller

Comment: Actually from the Laravel documentation this is the right way to pass a parameter to a view. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: You are actually right, https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_with

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi yes, but if i try i still got error.. so sorry i am new to use laravel

Comment: Can you specify in your question what version of Laravel are you using?